# start netcat server

Tags: linux, netcat

I can't simply start netcat for listening like I see in tutorials with a simple:

```
nc -l -p 11457
```

What am I doing wrong?
It throws me out the help:

```
usage: nc [-46CDdhklnrStUuvz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-O length]
  [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port] [-s source] [-T ToS]
  [-V rtable] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
  [-x proxy_address[:port]] [destination] [port]
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Did you read the man page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Ubuntu, download the netcat-traditional package.  The command would be `sudo apt-get install netcat-traditional`

For other Linux versions check out the sourceforge page for the most recent releases:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/netcat/files/netcat/0.7.1/
- http://nc110.sourceforge.net/

Apparently there are multiple versions. `netcat-openbsd` is installed by default and doesn't support the same switches as the traditional version.  Weird issue, hopefully this helps.

Comment: oh no!! I have fedora 16 and I can't find the tradional netcat rpm :(

Comment: ok got it!! but within another machine on my network I can't connect to my netcat using "netcat 192.168.1.2 11457" it simply dies

Comment: @hysoka44  Glad I could help.  We'll need more info to solve that issue.  If I helped, an upvote and/or check mark would be appreciated.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just ommit the `-l` flag and it should work. You are using a different version of netcat.

There is `netcat-openbsd` and `netcat-traditional`. The tutorials are probably using netcat-openbsd so install that if you wish:

```
apt-get remove netcat-traditional
apt-get install netcat-openbsd
```